# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack' when running npm start on angular 2 webpack starter

Tags: angular, webpack

I have cloned from here:

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Installed, with some warnings:

```
npm install typings webpack-dev-server rimraf webpack -g
```

At first it was complaining about RxJs - wanted version 2, but in package.json was version 4. I updated package.json so that RxJs version would be 2.

Warnings where those:

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd angular2-webpack-starter@4.0.0 npm run typings -- install (wd=/vagrant_data)
npm WARN engineStrict Per-package engineStrict (found in this package's package.json)
npm WARN engineStrict won't be used in npm 3+. Use the config setting `engine-strict` instead.
npm WARN unmet dependency /vagrant_data/node_modules/typedoc requires typescript@'1.6.2' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /vagrant_data/node_modules/typescript,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.8.9
npm WARN unmet dependency /vagrant_data/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/pretty-error/node_modules/renderkid requires utila@'~0.3' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /vagrant_data/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/node_modules/pretty-error/node_modules/utila,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.4.0
npm WARN unmet dependency /vagrant_data/node_modules/typings/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/node_modules/mkdirp requires minimist@'0.0.8' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /vagrant_data/node_modules/typings/node_modules/minimist,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.2.0
```

Now running

```
npm start

> angular2-webpack-starter@4.0.0 start /vagrant_data
> npm run server:dev


> angular2-webpack-starter@4.0.0 server:dev /vagrant_data
> webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/

root directory: /vagrant_data
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant_data/config/webpack.common.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)

npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "server:dev"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-webpack-starter@4.0.0 server:dev: `webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-webpack-starter@4.0.0 server:dev script 'webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-webpack-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "server:dev"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.1202353761
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.1202353761'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.1202353761']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.1202353761' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant_data/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-webpack-starter@4.0.0 start: `npm run server:dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-webpack-starter@4.0.0 start script 'npm run server:dev'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular2-webpack-starter package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run server:dev
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-webpack-starter
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.514887008
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.514887008'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'npm-debug.log.514887008']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'npm-debug.log.514887008' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant_data/npm-debug.log
```

From last line - npm-debug.log file I do not even see.

Why I am getting error that webpack is not found if when installing there was no such error?

I am now installing on vagrant image, but I tried to install on my mac computer and errors looks familiar.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow these steps:

1. Remove `package.json.lock` file from folder where your angular project is
2. Install angular cli lib by running `npm install -g @angular/cli`
3. Remove `node_modules` folder and install npm packages by running `npm install`
4. Rebuild `node-sass` binary by running `npm rebuild node-sass`
5. Run project with command `ng serve -o`

Answer (score 1):

When running an npm script like "npm start" and that script has a dependency on modules that define executable scripts, npm will look for the path to that executable on the node_modules.bin folder.

By installing the module using only:

```
npm install webpack
```

without the -g will do that, add the path to the node_modules.bin folder

installing a module using -g will make possible to you to run the command:

```
webpack
```

by yourself.

You can see more on how npm scripts work on [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#environment).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and i did go with local installation in my project folder here in `windows`. can you try install it in local `application` folder, using `npm install webpack`

Comment: when I run npm install webpack, it stops throwing the error. But still - why it does not install without running this command when it is in package.json?